# After WEbmatrix installation both VS2012 and Webmatrix is not working

Tags: iis-7.5, visual-studio-2012, iis-8, webmatrix-2

I think this is something that you have come across.

This has happened to me twice. I have installed VS 2012 which installs IIS 8 automatically on my machine. Then when I installed Webmatrix it installs IIS 7.5 and any of the programs are not working appropriately. In VS 2012, I can not run an MVC web project in localhost and I can not create a project in WebMatrix. Last time I did a system backup. So, I had to leave Webmatrix behind to save VS2012.

Then I installed IIS 7.5 again check the both things like [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7). But still the same problem exists.

I would like to know a precise answer to this problem and a solid answer to overcome this. Web Matrix is dependent on IIS7.5 and VS2012 is using IIS8. How can I use both the applications in the same machine.

Is it possible to run 2 IIS versions on the same machine?

But after installing IIS 7.5 my local host is working but not my VS nor Webmatrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems when I installed VS 2012, IIS 8 got installed along with the  package. Installing Webmatrix 2 installed IIS 7.5. Not sure why IIS 7.5 is getting installed when the system has IIS 8.
Anyways, when I tried running my website from Visual Studio (Selected IIS Express) or WebMatrix, I got a HTTP 500 error.
I resolved this by uninstalling IIS 7.5, repairing IIS 8.0 and then cleared my registry with the IIS 7.5's keys.
Please refer the below site for the step-by-step process.

http://www.latringo.me/post/2012/05/30/IIS-75-Express-kills-IIS-80-Express.aspx

My site is working fine now :).